# Constants from differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem, I've solved 2 diff equations and I have:

```
w1[y] == (E^(β*y))*(A1*cos[β*y] + 
     A2*sin[β*y]) + (E^(-β*y))*(A3*cos[β*y] + 
     A4*sin[β*y])

w2[y] == (E^(-β*y))*(A5*cos[β*y] + A6*sin[β*y])
```

I have also 6 equations to find constants A1-A6 :

```
w1''[0] == 0, w1'''[y] == -q*L , w1[L] == w2[L], w1'[L] == w2'[L], 
w1''[L] == w2''[L], w1'''[L] == w2'''[L]
```

How should I write it so I can find constants?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Kuba, could You possibly help me ?

Comment: Could You, please paste any link to example of smilar Solve use?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: @Peter Please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 5):

Correct `sin/cos` to `Sin/Cos`. Define your functions properly: `w1[y_] :=...`. Then put your conditions to `Solve` and done.

```
w1[y_] := (E^(β*y))*(A1*Cos[β*y] + A2*Sin[β*y]) + (E^(-β*y))*(A3*Cos[β*y] + 
     A4*Sin[β*y]);

w2[y_] := (E^(-β*y))*(A5*Cos[β*y] + A6*Sin[β*y]);

vars = Symbol["A" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[6]
```

> ```
> {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6}
> ```

```
Solve[
  {w1''[0] == 0, w1'''[y] == -q*L, w1[L] == w2[L], w1'[L] == w2'[L], 
   w1''[L] == w2''[L], w1'''[L] == w2'''[L]},
  vars
  ]
```

> [image]