# Equation solving problem

Tags: equation-solving

I have this code:

```
w1[y_] := 
  (E^(β*y))*(A1*Cos[β*y] + A2*Sin[β*y]) + (E^(-β*y))*(A3*Cos[β*y] + 
    A4*Sin[β*y]) + 2 q/k 
w2[y_] := 
  (E^(β*y))*(A5*Cos[β*y] + A6*Sin[β*y]) + (E^(-β*y))*(A7*Cos[β*y] + 
    A8*Sin[β*y]) + q/k
vars = Symbol["A" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[8]
```

> {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8}

```
Solve[
  {w1''[0] == 0, w1'''[0] == 0 , w1[L] == w2[L], w1'[L] == w2'[L], w1''[L] == w2''[L], 
    w1'''[L] == w2'''[L]}, 
  w2''[2 L] == 0, w2'''[2 L] == 0, vars]
```

When I try to evaluate the above, I get the message:

> Solve::bddom: Value Symbol[A[]1], Symbol[A[]2], Symbol[A[]3], Symbol[A[]4], Symbol[A[]5], Symbol[A[]6], Symbol[A[]7], Symbol[A[]8]} of the domain argument should be Complexes, Reals, Algebraics, Rationals, Integers, Primes, or Automatic. >>

I would like to ask you, what I can do better, so the programme finds constants?

Comment: Men, You are so unfriendly here. Why is so ?

Comment: There are various reasons why people are sometimes unfriendly to new users that are not even able to learn the very basics of a new language they try to use. I have seen the comments in your other question. Why don't you try to [read here](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/built-in-functions/) and ensure that your next questions cannot easily be found there?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80939/constants-from-differential-equations

Comment: The fourth bullet in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "...some proof of a **minimal Mathematica knowledge**." You have a basic syntax error.  The unfriendly remarks having been deleted, I don't know how unfriendly they were.  But you've put your braces `{}` in the wrong place (in particular, the right one `}`).

Answer (score 3):

Your `Solve` call looks like this

```
Solve[{ some equations }, w2''[2 L] == 0, w2'''[2 L] == 0, vars]
```

Why did you exclude the last equation from your list? When you write it like that, then *Mathematica* thinks your last equation is the list of variables and `vars` is the domain specification. This is what the error message tells you

> Solve::bddom: Value ... of the domain argument should be Complexes, Reals, Algebraics, Rationals, Integers, Primes, or Automatic. >>

Therefore, using this as `Solve` call works for me

```
Solve[{
  w1''[0] == 0, w1'''[0] == 0,
  w1[L] == w2[L], w1'[L] == w2'[L],
  w1''[L] == w2''[L], w1'''[L] == w2'''[L],
  w2''[2 L] == 0, 
  w2'''[2 L] == 0}, vars
]//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]